# FlashAir Execute on Write Event Properties

Tags: flashair

Using the dropbox sample code I am working on a Lua script that will run each time a new file is added (a photo in this case) to a specific folder. I see examples to iterate through a folders files to upload them each in turn. What I need is the properties that are passed to the file that will execute each time a new file is written. I'm hoping it will be passed the filename for the last file created so I can use that to upload the file directly to Dropbox or FTP site.

Answer (score 0):

HI someone in japan solved your doubt as the following.

> last_filepath = "" 
>   max_mod = 0 
>   fpath = "/DCIM/100__TSB"
>   for filename in lfs.dir(fpath) do
>   filepath = fpath .. "/" .. filename
>   mod = lfs.attributes( filepath, "modification" )
>   if mod > max_mod then
>       max_mod = mod
>       last_filepath = filepath
>   end 
>   end

basically it set a directory to search for the latest file with newest modification date/time.

details r here
http://dotnsf.blog.jp/archives/1040120555.html